# jquery/js checkbox values don't remove unchecking

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Eric Hynds jQuery MultiSelect Widget that is being populated from a javascript file. The issue is that a value with a space in it will not remove if it is then unchecked from the dropdown. Please see my fiddle of how it works and the issue http://jsfiddle.net/3u7Xj/106/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".multiselect").multiselect({
    header: "Choose up to 5 areas total",
    click: function (event, ui) {
        var number1 = $("#MDCselect").children(":checked").length,
            number2 = $("#Clinicalselect").children(":checked").length;

        if (ui.checked && ((number1 + number2 >= 2) || $(this).children(":checked").length >= 2)) {
            return false;
        }

        var lbl = ui.value;
        if (ui.checked) {
            var ctrl = '<input type="checkbox" name="chk" checked="checked" class="chk" id="' + lbl + '">';
            $("[id^=id]:checked").each(function () {
                $(this).nextAll('.holder:first').append('<div>' + ctrl + lbl + '</div>');
            });
        } else {
            $("[id^=id]:checked").each(function () {
                $(this).nextAll('.holder:first').find('#' + lbl).parent().remove();
            })
        }
    },
    selectedList: 5
});
$(".checkers").click(function () {
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).nextAll('.holder:eq(0)').find('div input').parent().remove();
    } else {
        var checkedOnes = $('#MDCselect').nextAll('.ui-multiselect-menu').find('ul li input:checked');
        $(".holder").html("");
        for (var i = 0; i < checkedOnes.length; i++) {
            var lbl = checkedOnes.eq(i).attr('value');
            var ctrl = '<input type="checkbox" name="chk" checked="checked" class="chk" id="' + lbl + '">';
            $("[id^=id]:checked").each(function () {
                $(this).nextAll('.holder:first').append('<div>' + ctrl + lbl + '</div>');
            });
        }
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is indeed the spaces. For every instance of `lbl` used as an ID (3 in total), you should instead use:

```
lbl.replace(/ /g, '')
```

For example:

```
$(this).nextAll('.holder:first').find('#' + lbl.replace(/ /g, ''))...
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3u7Xj/111/).

Comment: Good spot, but you still can't check and uncheck a value with space in it.

Comment: @Niklas I can't replicate in Chrome. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Right, thats just an option thats set up. Not the issue. If you check "this space" it does not remove it from a Main checkbox as "1" or "2" does.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly - I'm using the latest version of Firefox and I can reproduce it in the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: @James I'm using Chrome. Please let me know if the issue is not clear.

Comment: How to still show the space when it pops up if that is doable? My actual project has several words in the value that would look odd without spaces.

Comment: I've also noticed if there is more than 1 space it wont remove. ie:"this this space"

Comment: Given the potential for multiple spaces shouldn't you use a regex: `/\s/g` to perform the matching?

Comment: @James this works very well for 1 space in a value. Can this be edited to included all the spaces? check my updated fiddle with added space in the value. something like? `var label = .replace(/ /g, '');`

Comment: The `replace()` call here replaces *any* space with ''. This means `"Hello, world"` becomes `"Hello,world!"` just as `"Hello,    world!" would also become `"Hello,world!"`. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3u7Xj/109/. I've added multiple spaces between "3this" and "space".

Comment: @James here is your solution with multiple spaces. "2this this space" does not remove when unchecked. http://jsfiddle.net/3u7Xj/110/

Comment: @user3191137 oh I see. In that case simply use `lbl.replace(/ /g, '');`

Comment: @James I'm not sure I'm inserting that correctly, could you update your fiddle with the `(/ /g, '')`?

Comment: @James Thanks for the help, now I've noticed if theres a "," or or symbols it wont remove but I try and figure it out.